# Can you attach things to a force field?

Tags: rifts, palladium-system

In a Rifts campaign we encountered a train protected by a force field. Will duct tape stick to a force field? Could we duct tape a person or explosives to it?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a rule that specifically covers this. However, since a force field is not a physical object, it would have no specific 'surface' to attach the duct tape to. You might, with a generous ruling, be able to wrap some completely around the field and attach the tape to itself but, since the entire idea of a force field is to repel things, I doubt that it will stay in place once the train is in motion.

Comment: This answer would be improved with citations from the game material that bolster confidence in its accuracy.

Comment: A repulsive field might not have a surface, but a protective *force field* certainly does. Whether duct tape adheres to the surface of a ball of magical or electrical energy, though, is an open question.

Comment: @doppelgreener  *"citations from the game material"* :D good luck with that one